# flutter : pubspec.yaml no error but gradle failed in android studio

Tags: flutter, pubspec

My pubspec.yaml has no error, my app works perfectly on my emulator, but when I got to android studio (to add app logo or to create .aab) there is gradle failed.

I'm pretty sure this problem comes from my pubspec file, because when I create a new projet it works perfectly, but when I modify my pubspec, I can't open the projet in Android studio.

As I re-use lots of packages, I paste a pubspec from an other projet (Of course, I change the app id)

```
name: appid
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  auto_size_text:
  shared_preferences:
  firebase_core: ^1.0.3
  firebase_database: ^6.1.2
  uuid:
  flutter_statusbarcolor:
  flutter_admob_app_open:
  google_mobile_ads:
  open_ad_flutter:
  pull_to_refresh:
  flutter_launcher_icons:
  cached_network_image:
  url_launcher:
  firebase_messaging: ^11.1.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^5.0.0+4
  firebase_analytics:
  in_app_review:
  sendgrid_mailer:
  google_fonts:

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

It is quite annoying as I need to recreate a projet every time this happen.

I don't have errors, I got this message

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
The AbstractArchiveTask.destinationDir property has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. Please use the 
destinationDirectory property instead.
```

Comment: Please add the error stack as well.

Comment: I don't have errors, I add a warning I have

Answer (score 0):

This helps me for **Deprecated Gradle features were used in build**

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean
```